# Stacked barplot for tracing composition

Tags: r

I need to plot a set of data in a stacked barplot. The data are from six samples with three different compositions (M1, M1BIS, M2,M2BIS, M3 & M3BIS), and has been taken in three diferents points (surface(S), center(M) & bottom (G)) and two times (0 & 32 days).

I need to graph those data in a stacked barplot (one bar per sample and time) to see the salt concentration in the three points along time, and allde bars must have the same length (expressed in percentage)

```
    rdata <-
structure(list(Sample = c("M1", "M1", "M1", "M2", "M2", "M2", 
"M3", "M3", "M3", "M1 BIS", "M1 BIS", "M1 BIS", "M2 BIS", "M2 BIS", 
"M2 BIS", "M3 BIS", "M3 BIS", "M3 BIS", "M1", "M1", "M1", "M2", 
"M2", "M2", "M3", "M3", "M3", "M1 BIS", "M1 BIS", "M1 BIS", "M2 BIS", 
"M2 BIS", "M2 BIS", "M3 BIS", "M3 BIS", "M3 BIS"), Composition = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), t = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L), Value = c("1,72", 
"1,3", "4,12", "3,7", "2,88", "3,52", "1,38", "2,57", "6,89", 
"1,28", "0,85", "4,15", "0,71", "1,47", "4,77", "1,17", "1,37", 
"4,76", "4,16", "3,65", "3,39", "3,62", "4,04", "4,37", "2,77", 
"2,6", "3,23", "3,1", "3,34", "3,64", "3,68", "2,82", "3,12", 
"4,03", "3,87", "4,27"), Point = c("G", "M", "S", "G", "M", "S", 
"G", "M", "S", "G", "M", "S", "G", "M", "S", "G", "M", "S", "S", 
"M", "G", "S", "M", "G", "S", "M", "G", "S", "M", "G", "S", "M", 
"G", "S", "M", "G")), .Names = c("Sample", "Composition", "t", 
"Value", "Point"), row.names = c(NA, -36L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're looking for. Perhaps it would help if you showed us what you've tried thus far...

Comment: I´m trying to plot the evolution of salt concentration in a cured jam along time, at the surface, the middle and at the center of the piece. We use 3 types of curing salts (composition). I´m not sure if this is what you are asking to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, I hope.

```
library(reshape2)
rdata$Value <- gsub(",", ".", rdata$Value)
rdata$Value <- as.numeric(rdata$Value)

rdataWide <- dcast(data=rdata, formula = Point ~ Sample + t, value.var = "Value")
rdataWide[,-1] <- t(t(rdataWide[, -1])/colSums(rdataWide[, -1]))

par(xpd=T)
barplot(as.matrix(rdataWide[, -1]), col=2:4, space = 0.25, width=0.5, las=2)
legend(x = 0.25, y=1.25, legend = rdataWide[,1], col = 2:4, pch = 15, bty = "n", ncol = 3)
```

[image]

### Edit:

it should be `par(xpd=T)` not `ppar(xpd=T)`, this allows rendering outside of the plot space. with it set to false the legend gets clipped.

I also added the `library(reshape2)` call. My apologies for the oversight.

Comment: Yes, thats is what I need, but I´m don´t understand how to do it

Comment: but legend doesn´t appear

Comment: @Rafa Repiso, there were two typos in my answer which I have now fixed and made note of in the answer. The legend should display now.